# Remove punctuations except intra-digit punctuations

Tags: python, regex

Is there a way to remove all punctuations in a string, but retaining hyphen and intra-digit punctuations?

```
Hello! this episode is thirty-five minutes long, 35.26 mins to be precise.
```

should be:

```
Hello this episode is thirty-five minutes long 35.26 mins to be precise
```

Comment: And what is the *programming* problem you have here? Please post the code that fails, or the question will be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` with a *positive lookahead*:

```
In [165]: re.sub('\W(?=\s|$)', '', s)
Out[165]: 'Hello this episode is thirty-five minutes long 35.26 mins to be precise'
```

---

**Details**

```
\W      # any character that is not a letter or digit
(?=     # positive lookahead
\s      # whitespace
|       # regex OR
$       # EOL
)
```

Answer (score 3):

A variant can be achieved with the newer `regex` module:

```
\w+[-.]+\w+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[!,.]+
```

Broken down:

```
\w+[-.]+\w+    # 1+ word characters, followed by - or ., another 1+ wc
(*SKIP)(*FAIL) # all of these shall fail
|              # or
[!,.]+         # one of !,. but possibly more
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/wP5XfA/1/).

---

In `Python`:

```
import regex as re

string = "Hello! this episode is thirty-five minutes long, 35.26 mins to be precise."

rx = re.compile(r'\w+[-.]+\w+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[!,.]+')
string = rx.sub('', string)
print(string)
# Hello this episode is thirty-five minutes long 35.26 mins to be precise
```